# Python flask use buttons to trigger scripts

Tags: python, linux, button, flask, html

I was investigating the web, mainly getting my self confused about several things.

First - what I need. my company runs java applications on our linux servers that non technological people uses. sometimes we have to restart those programs, but first kill them.

I've built small tool (runs on linux) that uses "jps -lm |grep -v Jps" to recover all java processes, then using splits and patterns to make something that looks like it:

```
You have those programs running:
1. Java A
2. Java B
3. Java C
4. Exit
5. Refresh
```

They choose a number, It asks for approval, if allowed, kills the process ("kill procId") and restarts (while loop until they type 4 which triggeres "break").

Now, I wanted to take it to one level above, using web browser to minimize their appereance near my linux servers (sys admin).

Now, I've found that flask would be great for me, created a web page, even managed to make it available all over the web.

What I intend to do is that the value of my "jps -lm |grep -v Jps" would be inserted into the html file when someone reaches the webpage.
when the html is ready, they will be redirected to it, push the appropriate button, an "onclick=alert('are you sure?')" will pop up and if approved that will trigger a
"subprocess.Popen('kill '+procId, stdout.subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)" command that will kill the process, redirecting them to the page where my script maps the current running java that will redirect them to the buttons page.

I'm able to do everything except the buttons part. have no idea how to make it available to the python after pressed.

Would appriciate any help. for the mapping script I intended to use this solution: [Create a hyperlink (or button) that executes a python script and then redirects when script completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903615/create-a-hyperlink-or-button-that-executes-a-python-script-and-then-redirects) .

sorry if my question is built badly, would appriciate any help with this as well!

Thanks!

Comment: you should design flask url endpoint, which should accept json payload, containing whatever necessary information (like command and their parameters) on button press. your controller can then execute appropriate script

Comment: I'm having really hard time figuring it out, cant understand why. could you help me with any code example? sorry if its considered rude or just bothering.

Comment: you have to compose a ajax request on a button press(you can read about it) and send this request to your flask controller, parse the request and get the relevant parameters. and then you can execute that script

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example below I hope that helps

if you are using inline javascript, then you don't have to use this variable and can access `url_for()` from the ajax request. If you are using a separate javascript file, then you have to put this variable in your template since `.js` files don't cannot render jinja2 code like `{{}}`

```
var flask_endpoint = "{{url_for('endpoint_name')}}"
```

ONLY IN THE CASE YOUR APP USES CSRF USE THIS:

```
var csrftoken = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

    $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
            }
        }
    })
```

IF NOT THEN SKIP THE ABOVE

Your javascript should look like this (you don't have to use the `done()` callback

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function(){

   var data = {'key': 'some value'};

   $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : flask_endpoint,
       data: JSON.stringify(data),
       contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
   }).done(function (result) {
       alert(result);
   });

   alert('data has been sent to the server');
});
```

below is how your python code should look like

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/ajax_endpoint', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def endpoint_name():
    # check if the request type is POST (we defined POST for our ajax request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['key'] # this is the key in our data object

        # do whatever you want with the data
```